# closing bootstrap popover doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have the following js code

```
$('#myelemt').popover({placement: 'right', title: 'What is this',
    content: 'content content content content content content content content content content content ', trigger: 'manual', html: 'true', container: '.wrap'});

$('#myelemt').click(function(e) {
    $('#myelemt').popover('show');
    $('.popover-title').append('<button type="button" class="close close_help">&times;</button>');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.close_help').click(function(e) {

    $(this).parents('#myelemt').popover('hide');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I want to close the popover when the .`close_help` is clicked, but it doesn't work. I tried several ways of getting to the parent `.popover` to `hide` it but it doesn't work. The above is one of those ways

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guyisra/jmLs9/1/) simulation

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413057/how-to-insert-close-button-in-popover-for-bootstrap/13413660#13413660

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmLs9/2/)

I did changes in the below line only

```
$('.popover-title').append('<button type="button" class="close close_help" onclick="$(&quot;#myelemt&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>');
```

Let me know your comments.