# Bootstrap popover manual close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I need several popovers on a page with manual close.Twitter examples on a [Live Demo](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips) section shows this functionality but I cant reach it.Who can recommend plug-in (tooltip) with such functionality?

Comment: You can manually close the tooltip by calling `$('#element').tooltip('hide')` and handle the show on your own by `$('#element').tooltip('show')`

Comment: Please have a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413057/how-to-insert-close-button-in-popover-for-bootstrap/27306598#27306598). The answer from Chris or my answer there is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually control the open or close of the Bootstrap Popup (no additional plugin required)..

```
$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
$('#btnToggleTip').click(function(){

  $('#tip1').tooltip('toggle'); // <-- alternately use 'show' or 'hide' here

})
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/97094