# Bootstrap popover, close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Im did the following popover: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ca4h0a0q/

```
<a class='danger' data-placement='above' title="Popover Title" href='#'>Click</a>
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
 <button class="close">
  x
  </button>
  <div>This is your div content</div> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click",".close",function(){
    $(".danger").trigger("click");  
  });

  $('.danger').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
    }
  });
});
```

For closing the popover, due to this bug: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16732 I had to trigger a click event on the button that opened it. I don't like this solution much. Any better way of doing this?

Comment: Check this question, there are various ways to add close button to popover mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413057/how-to-insert-close-button-in-popover-for-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I got it working this way.

```
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
  <button class="close" onclick="$('.danger').popover('hide').trigger('click')">
    x
  </button>
<div>This is your div content</div>
```

And the js...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.danger').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace this

```
$("body").on("click",".close",function(){
    $(".danger").trigger("click");  
});
```

With this

```
$("body").on("click",".close",function(){
    $(this)
        .closest("a.danger")
        .trigger("click");  
});
```

More on `closest`: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

This way if you have **multiple** popovers or an element with the class `danger` they won't be triggered too.

Comment: @JoelAlvarezMyrrie did my answer help you out? Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

When you know the ID (or class or anything else to identify) of the source element:

```js
$('#<id>').popover('hide');
```

or

```js
$('#<id>').popover('dispose');
```

will work fine.

If you add the class `popover_show` at creation, like

```js
$(info.jsEvent.srcElement).addClass('popover_show');
```

you can use the .popover_show class to close/dispose all open popovers:

```js
$('.popover_show').popover('dispose');
```

or

```js
$('.popover_show').popover('dispose');
```

The rough way to delete all popovers (if you have trouble or like to clean up).

```
$('.popover').remove();
```

(if you have nested popovers, manuell added DOM-Elements to Popover, hidden elements ...)