# Insert a close button in bootstrap popover plugin

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-popover

I want to insert a close button in bootstrap popover plugin on the top right corner as shown in the picture and I have tried a lot of ways that other people proposed on the internet but it's not working, maybe I did it wrong way..

[Something like the red close button on the top right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DNUa.png)

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container navbar-cart">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li>
               <a id="cart-popover" class="btn" data-placement="left" title="Shopping Cart">
                 <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                 <span class="badge"></span>
                 <span class="total_price">RM 0.00</span>
               </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
   <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
    <span id="cart_details"></span>
    <div align="right">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="check_out_cart">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Check Out
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear_cart">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Clear
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

//show cart
     $('#cart-popover').popover({
       html : true,
       content:function(){
          return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
       }
    });

$('.close').on('click', function (event) {
        $('#popover_content_wrapper').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert close button in popover for bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413057/how-to-insert-close-button-in-popover-for-bootstrap)

Comment: yeah haha but I tried the solutions there , it's not working for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is your expected output :

read more here : http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/#options

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#cart-popover').popover({
       html : true,
       title:function(){
          return $('.popover_title').html();
       },
       content:function(){
          return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
       }
       
    });
      
});    

$(document).on('click','.close-popover',function(){
  $('#cart-popover').popover('hide');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container navbar-cart">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li>
               <a id="cart-popover" class="btn" data-placement="left">
                  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                 <span class="badge"></span>
                 <span class="total_price">RM 0.00</span>
               </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="popover_title" style="display: none">
<h6>Shopping Cart<span class="close-popover float-right text-danger "><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span></h6>
</div>
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
    <span id="cart_details"></span>
                 
    <div align="right">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="check_out_cart">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Check Out
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear_cart">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Clear
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did but only more than 15 reputation are allowed to vote :'(