# Popover with a div container showing buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is a bootstrap popover where buttons are showed after the "Click" link is pressed. The problem is that the buttons don't want to become available in the popover-content container. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .popover-content{width:200px;height:100px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">Click</a>
  <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    <p>Here I want to place my Buttons:</p>
    <!-- But this is not working -->
    <button>1</button>
  </div>
<script>
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover(
  {
    html: true,
 content: function()
  {
    return $('#popover-content').html();
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this topic will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413057/how-to-insert-close-button-in-popover-for-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this option to your popover:

```
sanitize: false
```

Working demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .popover-content{width:200px;height:100px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">Click</a>
  <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    <p>Here I want to place my Buttons:</p>
    <button>1</button>
  </div>
<script>
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover(
  {
    html: true,
    sanitize: false,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Note: this option is not documented in [Bootstrap's docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers-usage). I just found it by looking at their [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.4.1/js/popover.js#L51).